# Template and constexpr deduction at compiletime dependent on compiler and optimization flags

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, cuda, constexpr

The following question is condensed from a much larger code. Therefore some expressions seem to be an overkill or unnecessary, but are crucial to the original code.

Consider having a struct, which contains compile time constants and a simple container class:

```
template<typename T> struct CONST
{
    static constexpr T ONE()
    {
         return static_cast<T>( 1 );
    }
};

template<typename T> class Container
{
public:
    using value_type = T;
    T value;
};
```

Now having a template function, that has a "specialization" for types offering a `value_type`:

```
template<typename T> void doSomething( const typename T::value_type& rhs )
{}
```

Now I would expect, that this should work:

```
template<typename T> class Tester
{
public:
    static constexpr T ONE = CONST<T>::ONE();

    void test()
    {
        doSomething<Container<T>>( ONE );
    }
};
```

The interesting point is, that the compiler does not complain about the definition of `Tester<T>::ONE`, but its usage. Further it does not complain, if I use `CONST<T>::ONE()` or even `static_cast<T>( ONE )` instead of `ONE` in the function call. However, both should be known at compile time and therefore usable.
So my first question is: Does the compiler in the cases, where it works, even do the calculations at compile time?

I checked it with the `g++-5`, `g++-6` and the `clang-3.8` compiler using the `-std=c++14` flag. They all complain

```
undefined reference to `Tester<int>::ONE'
```

although all used features are, as far as I know, in the standard and should therefore be supported. Interestingly the compilation is successful as soon as I add an optimization flag `O1`, `O2` or `O3`. So my second question is: Is there an strategy of the compiler doing compile time calculations only, if optimization flags are active? I would have expected that at least things, that are declared as compile time constant are *always* deduced!

The last part of my question covers the NVIDIA `nvcc` compiler (version 8.0). As I can only pass `-std=c++11` to it, it may be that some features are generally not covered. However, using one of the host compiler above, it complains

```
error: identifier "Tester<int> ::ONE" is undefined in device code
```

even if an optimization flag is passed! This is obviously the very same problem as above, but while the questions above are more academical (because I can simply use an optimization flag to get rid of the problem), here it is really a problem (concerning the fact that I do not know, what is done at compile time when I use the workarounds mentioned above - and this is also uglier). So my third question is: Is there a way of using the optimizations also in device code?

The following code is an MWE for pure host and also for the nvcc compiler:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

#ifdef __CUDACC__
    #define HD __host__ __device__
#else
    #define HD
#endif


template<typename T> struct CONST
{
    HD static constexpr T ONE()
    {
        return static_cast<T>( 1 );
    }
};


template<typename T> class Container
{
public:
    using value_type = T;
    T value;
};


template<typename T> HD void doSomething( const typename T::value_type& rhs ) {}


template<typename T> class Tester
{
public:
    static constexpr T ONE = CONST<T>::ONE();

    HD void test()
    {
        doSomething<Container<T>>( ONE );
        // doSomething<Container<T>>( static_cast<T>( ONE ) );
        // doSomething<Container<T>>( CONST<T>::ONE() );
    }
};


int main()
{
    using t = int;

    Tester<t> tester;
    tester.test();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: regarding the first part of your question see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452952/c-linker-error-with-class-static-constexpr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between this:

```
doSomething<Container<T>>( ONE );
```

as opposed to these two:

```
doSomething<Container<T>>( static_cast<T>( ONE ) );
doSomething<Container<T>>( CONST<T>::ONE() );
```

is that in the first case you're binding a reference directly to `ONE` and the others you are not. More specifically, you are *odr-using* `ONE` in the first case but not the other two. When you *odr-use* an entity, it needs a definition, and `ONE` is currently declared but not defined.

You need to define it:

```
template<typename T>
class Tester
{
public:
    // declaration
    static constexpr T ONE = CONST<T>::ONE();
    // ..
};

// definition
template <typename T>
constexpr T Tester<T>::ONE;
```

Comment: Thx. This is definitely the answer for the cpu case. But as long as I am not doing something terribly wrong, it does still not work with the `nvcc` compiler... . The situation should be the same, shouldn't?

Comment: I just recognize: Why did it work with optimization flags? Are they just guessing right (perhaps potentially also wrong in more complicated cases?) or is something else happening?

Comment: @marlam Can't help you with nvcc, don't know. It shouldn't just ever work, and could actually be ill-formed NDR like most other odr violations.

Comment: For the CUDA case, I think this is a real parser problem. The constexpr is not getting correctly propagated into the device compilation trajectory. But the point regarding definition is this answer is perfectly correct.

Comment: I state this question as accepted, unless the lack of the nvcc problem. But as it turned out to be different problems (which I did not mention questioning), it will be best to reask the nvcc question with a clearer focus on that particular problem. Thanks again for your fast and nice answer!