# constexpr static member before/after C++17

Tags: c++, static, constexpr, c++17

As far as I can see, a very common situation is something like

```
template<int i> class Class
{
public:
    static constexpr int I = i;
    static constexpr int J = constexprFunction(i);
    // further Class implementation
};
```

Almost as common I see the mistake (in fact most of my questions here are because I forgot it and did not know, what the proper question had been) to forget the additional definition if the member are odr-used:

```
template<int i> constexpr int Class<i>::I;
template<int i> constexpr int Class<i>::J;
```

Now I read [cppreference: Definitions and ODR](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) and [cppreference: static members](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static), which state, that this is deprecated for C++17. This seems great to me, because it avoids a lot of errors. But there are other questions, that came up:

1) Has this change other reasons than making the additional definitions useless? (See also last paragraph of this question)

2) In the last example of [cppreference: static members](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) it seems also to apply on `const static` member - but the rule states only the `constexpr` member. Will it apply on `const static` member or not?

3) All examples I found were using a simple definition like `Class::I` - does it all hold also for the situation at `Class:J` with `constexpr` functions?

A brief state what the best practices are before C++17 and with C++17 would be great. All in all this seems a very tricky change to me, because it will make a lot of code, which was "ill-formed non diagnostic required" before, to good code (as far as I understand...). And consequently there will be code produced, that is still "ill-formed non diagnostic required" with older (pre 17) compiler - but these will not complain, as long as no odr-use is required.

**Edit**: Corrected the text, suggested by Aaron McDaid.

Comment: I think the last example on static data members was an editing error (now fixed): 9.2.3.2[class.static.data]p3 says, for "non-volatile non-inline const static data member", "The member shall still be defined in a namespace scope if it is odr-used"

Comment: I'm confused by the text in the question currently:  *"mistake  ... to give a definition if the members are odr-used"*. Surely you mean, in C++11 for example, that it is a mistake to *fail* to give a definition? Did you forget a negation? (Sorry if this seems very pedantic, but I genuinely don't know this well enough to be sure of the intention here )

Comment: @AaronMcDaid Yes, that it is true. I fixed it. I clearly meant that it is necessary  to give the additional definition in C++11, but this is no longer true in C++17. Therefore I tried to explain my confusion in the purpose of downwards compatibility in the last paragraph.

Comment: @Cubbi: Is is possible, that this feature is not implemented to the gnu compiler yet? I tried it with the MWE of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642434/template-and-constexpr-deduction-at-compiletime-dependent-on-compiler-and-optimi), compiling with `g++-6` and `-std=C++17`. It still complains about the lack of a definition! Or am I thinking something stupid?

Comment: @marlam This feature is not even listed in the gcc [compliance status table](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx1z). It is available in [clang 3.9](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html#cxx17). It is also available in MSVC 2015 (though in this case beause of a lack of Standardness)

Comment: If the definitions should be present under C++11 (and C++14), but are not needed (or even forbidden) under C++17, is there a simple `#ifdef` that could be wrapped around the definitions? Perhaps the standard should specify a macro `_CONSTEXPR_STATIC_DEFNS_NOT_NEEDED` or something monstrous like that :-)

Comment: @mariam try gcc HEAD 7.0.0 on http://melpon.org/wandbox/

Comment: @Cubbi: This also does not work without the additional definition. Seems to be like metalfox suggests. Only the clang HEAD does work properly with this feature.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This change is due to the inline variables proposal ([P0386](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0386r2.pdf)). `static constexpr` will imply `inline`, making definitions redundant.

> In Annex D, add a new subclause, “Redeclaration of static constexpr data members”, D.X, with the following content:
>   For compatibility with prior C++ International Standards, a constexpr static data member may be redundantly redeclared outside the class with no initializer. This usage is deprecated.
>
> [Example:
>
> ```
> struct A {
> static constexpr int n = 5; // definition (declaration in C++2014)
> };
> const int A::n; // redundant declaration (definition in C++2014)
> ```
>
> —end example]

Regarding to your questions:

> Has this change other reasons than making the additional definitions useless?

In essence, no. Yet it has additional uses besides the one you noted (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043442/what-is-an-inline-variable-and-what-is-it-useful-for)). This proposal was controversial because it might encourage the use of a mutable global state.

> Will it apply on `const static` member or not?

No. *Unless* you annotate it as `inline`.

> does it all hold also for the situation at `Class:J` with `constexpr` functions?

Yes. The proposal deals with linking but does not affect initialization rules.

Comment: I know it is a quote, but isn't it a bit confusing to declare a `constexpr` and to define it as `const`? Because this seems to me to be not the same...

Comment: @marlam It surprised me too. I think it is a typo.

Comment: It was really difficult to understand the OP's questions, the English wording is confusing. Maybe this wasn't asked directly, but: Does `static constexpr` mean the same as `constexpr` in C++17? It's always confused me why I'd use one or the other in a class declaration for constant member variables. If it's `constexpr`, it can't be changed, so isn't `static` redundant? Also now if `constexpr` means `inline`, isn't it the same as saying `static inline` which makes no sense?

Comment: @void.pointer `static constexpr` is the same as `static inline constexpr` in C++17, but `constexpr` alone does not imply `inline constexpr`. Use `static constexpr` for member variables ([example in the standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/atomics.types.generic#atomics.types.operations-5)). Use `inline constexpr` for global variables ([example in the standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/pair.piecewise)).