# google-test and static constexpr member

Tags: c++, googletest

From the [FAQ](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/FAQ.md):

If your class has a static data member:

```
// foo.h

class Foo {
    ...
    static const int kBar = 100;
};
```

You also need to define it outside of the class body in foo.cc:

`const int Foo::kBar;  // No initializer here.`

Otherwise your code is **invalid C++**, and may break in unexpected ways. In particular, using it in Google Test comparison assertions (EXPECT_EQ, etc) will generate an "undefined reference" linker error.

If instead of `static const` I use `static constexpr`, should I still have definition in foo.cc or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++11 and C++14, you need a separate definition of `foo` if is it [odr-used](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#ODR-use), even in the case of `constexpr`.  However for the `constexpr` case, the separate definition [will not be required anymore in C++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39646958/constexpr-static-member-before-after-c17).