# constexpr data member defined in .h is unresolved in .cpp only on -std=c++14 and below

Tags: c++, c++17, linker-errors, constexpr

The following only links successfully with `-std=c++17` or above. `-std=c++14` or below gives an unresolved external error:

```
In function `C::f()':
C.cpp:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `C::kConstant'
```

Why doesn't this work with the c++14 standard and does work with the c++17 standard? (tested with both GCC and Clang)

And why does the commented-out workaround work even on c++14?

**C.h**

```
#pragma once

class C {
public:
    static constexpr int kConstant = 10;
    int f();
};
```

**C.cpp**

```
#include "C.h"

#include <algorithm>

int C::f()
{
    // This only works with -std=c++17 or above
    return std::min (1, kConstant); 

    // This works even with -std=c++14
//    return std::min (1, static_cast<int> (kConstant));
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "C.h"

int main()
{
    C c;
    c.f();
}
```

[Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BznRbSOkssgQ7qV6)

Update: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39646958/constexpr-static-member-before-after-c17) question isn't an exact duplicate, but has an answer which answers most of my question. It doesn't answer why the workaround works with `-std=c++14`, though, and the original doesn't. Is it perhaps because in the original the variable is *odr-used*, and in the workaround it is not?

Comment: The question isn't an exact duplicate, though the answer there answers most of my question. (It doesn't answer why the commented-out workaround works even with `-std=c++14`)

Comment: The commented workaround creates an `int` prvalue. The const reference `std::min` expects thus doesn't try to bind to `kConstant` (and odr use it due to it). I edited in another duplicate that addresses it (which also has an answer mentioning a cast).

Comment: @StoryTeller Awesome, thank you!

Comment: @StoryTeller By the way - isn't it an issue (in both compilers) that I do not get a warning in `-std=c++14` due to trying to initialize the non-inline static constexpr member in its declaration, which should have no effect, rather than in its (missing) definition?

Comment: The declaration must contain an initializer. So there is no problem. That's what facilitates using it as a constexpr, so long as it isn't odr-used.

Comment: @StoryTeller Of course. Thanks!