# How to access a constexpr string that is defined in a struct?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, constexpr

How to properly access the string "bye" from the struct?

```
#include <iostream>
static constexpr char hi[] = "hi";
struct S{ static constexpr char bye[] = "bye"; };

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  typedef struct S ST;

  std::cout << hi << std::endl;              // this prints "hi" 
  std::cout << sizeof(ST::bye) << std::endl; // this correctly prints 4
  std::cout << ST::bye << std::endl;         // this does not compile with "undefined reference"
}
```

I'm working with a c++ framework that has some configuration in this format (in multiply nested structs even) to make its values available during compile time. I'm not deep enough into C++ to grasp the underlying issue here. Also I cannot argue about why this approach on implementing the configuration was chosen and cannot change it.

Comment: Compile with c++17

Comment: Does this answer your question? [constexpr static member before/after C++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39646958/constexpr-static-member-before-after-c17)

Comment: [here](https://godbolt.org/z/7VTYwE)

Comment: Use the `::` operator to access static members of a class, as in `S::bye`

Comment: `typedef struct S ST;` -> `using ST = S;`

Comment: Thanks KamilCuk! The link showed me how to fix the issue. But what is the underlying reason why 'sizeof' is working and the printing the string isn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be made working by redefining the static constexpr outside the struct:

```
#include <iostream>
static constexpr char hi[] = "hi";
struct S{ static constexpr char bye[] = "bye"; };

constexpr char S::bye[]; // <<< this line was missing

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  typedef struct S ST;

  std::cout << hi << std::endl;              // this prints "hi" 
  std::cout << sizeof(ST::bye) << std::endl; // this correctly prints 4
  std::cout << ST::bye << std::endl;         // Now this prints "bye"
}
```

Or by compiling using c++17 which makes this obsolete.

Related links:

- [constexpr static member before/after C++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39646958/constexpr-static-member-before-after-c17)
- [What does it mean to "ODR-use" something?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19630570/what-does-it-mean-to-odr-use-something)