# nested enum vs constexpr static member variable

Tags: c++, enums, constexpr, undefined-reference, c++17

When the `constexpr` was introduced to C++ I started to write my compile time constants as `constexpr static` member variables instead of using the `enum` hack.

So I know about the subtle difference that you cannot take the address of a constant defined with `enum`, where in the `constexpr` case you can. Since you don't want to do that, so it's fine. But now I stumbled upon some code where I'm not sure whether you might accidentally take the address.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    constexpr static unsigned c1 = 1;
    enum{ c2 = 2 };
};

template<typename T>
auto foo(T&& p)
{
    return p;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << foo(A::c1) << " " << foo(A::c2) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`gcc 7` and `clang 4` will compile this code just fine, where any older versions of these compilers will complain about an undefined reference of `A::c1`.

If I understand this correctly, the function `foo` takes the `A::c1` expression as some kind of reference and thus needs to take its address, which leads to the undefined reference.

What is the correct behavior?
Does the standard require me to define the member variable just to be able to use them in the context of perfect forwarding?

**Edit:**
I just noticed, `gcc 7` as well as `clang 4` will also complain about the undefined reference if you use `-std=c++14` instead of `-std=c++1z`. So was there a related change in the standard?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Linker Error With Class static constexpr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452952/c-linker-error-with-class-static-constexpr)

Comment: @m.s. much may have changed since C++11, as that question is tagged.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38043566/440558) about inline member variable definitions.

Comment: @m.s. I would say the answer you linked does not answer my question, since I'm not asking for a fix. My question is about whether the standard really requires me to define such members in a separate compilation unit just to be able to use it in the context of perfect forwarding. But the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38043566/440558) of Some programmer dude gives some insight.

Comment: Yes, reference binding means odr-use, and anything that's odr-used needs to have a definition.