# Why can a "const static int" member be initialized within a class, but not a "const static other" member?

Tags: c++, static-members

Look at the code below, this `const static int num1 = 8;` compiles. However, the `const static double num2 = 8.8;` code gives an error. Their modifiers are all `const static`, so why does `int` work, but `double` and other floating-point types result in an error?

```cpp
struct S {
    const static int num1 = 8;       // OK
    const static double num2 = 8.8;  // error
};
```

I've tried some built-in types of C++ and found that

- integer members such as `int`, `short`, `long`, and `char` can be defined with `const static` in the class and directly initialized, while
- floating-point members such as `float` and `double` can not.

This confuses me a lot.

Comment: Why same identifier for both?, did you try with different identifier name?

Comment: If it matters to your question, `constexpr static double a = 8.8;` is the affordance that was added to the language to support this.  `constexpr static inline double a = 8.8;` even better.

Comment: Try `constexpr static double a = 8.8;` Also, this question may be similar to [Static const double in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777541/static-const-double-in-c). See [constexpr specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr).

Comment: It is a specific exception for `const`-qualified integral and enumeration types that is there only for historical reasons. If you are using C++17 or later you can ignore it and use either `constexpr` instead of `const` if you want the value to be a compile-time constant or `inline` otherwise and you will be able to initialize any static member this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as a matter of fact, `static const double` members **can** be initialized in the class—**if** you declare them `inline`. If the value you want to initialize it to also happens to be a constant expression, then you can declare it `constexpr`, in which case you do not need to declare it `inline` because a `static constexpr` data member is automatically inline.

However, when a `static const double` member is not inline, then it means that exactly one translation unit is responsible for supplying the *definition* of that member, and the definition is responsible for the initialization. Because a class definition needs to be `#include`d into every translation unit that wants to access members of that class, it means the *declaration* of the member inside the class should not be a definition (because that would lead to multiple definitions). As a result, you must provide a single definition of the static member somewhere outside the class, and that single definition is the one that is responsible for initializing it.

Answer (score 5):

`float` data types are non-integral types, which requires [`constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) specifier instead of `const` :

```
struct S {
    constexpr static double af = 8.8;
    const static int ai = 8; 
};
```

The original error message could help you debugging this issue:

```
error: 'constexpr' needed for in-class initialization of static data member 
'const double myclass::af' of non-integral type
```

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea about "why float-point types can't be initialized in class with `const double` while other built-in types can", but I can provide other ways to initialize `const static` members in class:

1. Instead of writing `const double a = 8;`, you can write `constexpr double a = 8;`, the difference between these two can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116003/whats-the-difference-between-constexpr-and-const?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C326.9839)
2. You can initialize it outside the class like:

   ```cpp
   class myclass {
       public:
           const static double a;
   };

   const double myclass::a = 8;
   ```